# How to implement redmine as SaaS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, redmine, saas

I am planning to use redmine as SaaS application with multi-tenant feature. I have successfully loaded redmine into the heroku but now i am in a blank position didn't know how and where to start.
Installed redmine can be accessed via http://dreamredmine.herokuapp.com/

I tried "rails-stripe-membership-saas" for the billing but i dont know how do i integrate it with redmine apps to create an automatic SaaS application in a multi-tenant architecture.
This installed "rails-stripe-membership-saas" can be accedded via http://spc-saas.herokuapp.com/

I tried searching for similar thread and it leads me to [Ruby on rails SaaS application where to begin, what tools to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255536/ruby-on-rails-saas-application-where-to-begin-what-tools-to-use)  which is pretty similar to my concept but converting the already built application "redmine" into SaaS was a problem for me.